# Biographical details of Rav Gidel?

Tags: sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, rabbis, biography

I have seen many statements in the talmud such as 'Rav Gidel said that Rav said...". I would like to know where I can find some biographical details of the life of Rav Gidel. Are there published works or online resources which have a biography of Rav Gidel?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rav_Giddel

Comment: תנאים ואמוראים - ביוגרפיות: תולדותיו של רב גידל 
אמורא בבלי בדור השני - השלישי. תלמידו של רב (עירובין י"ז ע"א), וכן קיבל משמואל (נדרים ט"ז ע"ב). אחר פטירתו של רב היה לתלמידו של ר"ה (יבמות ס"ד ע"ב), וכן קיבל מרב חייא בר יוסף (שבת ז' ע"א) ומרב ירמיה בר אבא (בכורות ל"ו ע"ב). הלך לא"י. קיבל מרב יוחנן (נדה כ"ד ע"א). בא"י היה לו דין ודברים עם רבי אבא (קידושין נ"ט ע"א). ר"ז אמר משמו (ברכות מ"ט ע"א). גם רבא בר רב הונא קיבל ממנו (קידושין מ"ב ע"א). This is Bar Ilan's biography.

Comment: @mevaqesh I think this is like an answer.

Comment: @rikitikitembo If you are interested, I will post the above as an answer.

Comment: @Yishai read the wiki article... wondering if the second and last paragraphs are somehow connected... Think that's a question worth asking?

Comment: @isacc, good question.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting book about biographical details of the sages of Talmud is [Who's Who in the Talmud](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568211139) by Shulamis Frieman in which covers every personality if mentioned in the Talmud, it presents information like the place/time of birth or the place/time where that sage was born, teacher, disciple, colleagues, family, job, teachings and the source where he is mentioned.

From this [Google Books search](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9PToGLIBt6UC&lpg=PP1&dq=inauthor%3A%22Shulamis%20Frieman%22&pg=PA159#v=onepage&q=Gidal%20(Gidol)&f=false) you can see a few references for what you are looking for.