# Encyclopedia of Tzaddikim

Tags: jewish-books, rabbis, tzaddikim, biography

Sheimos HaTzaddikim is a very unique prayer within Breslov which is pretty much reciting the names of many righteous people, from characters within the Tanach to fairly modern figures.

I could not find an informative page for those who haven't heard of the prayer, but I did find the text of the whole thing on ויקיטקסט, which you can see [here](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A6%D7%93%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9D).

[The Breslov Siddur](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1928822835) says the following:

> The very names of the *tzaddikim* possess a profound mystical significance. Rebbe Nachman's teachings on this subject prompted Reb Noson to compile the *Sheimos HaTzaddikim* (Names of the *Tzaddikim*), which includes all the *tzaddikim* in the Bible and in rabbinic literature.

There are many, many, figures in this compilation of which I am not familiar with. Is there a book or somewhere online in which I could look up the name of a tzaddik and read a short biography?

Such an encyclopedia would be useful even for those not reciting Sheimos HaTzaddikim, as sometimes you might read about a Tanna, Rishon, etc. you don't know who is.

Comment: Try Wikipedia in English, Hebrew, and Yiddish, Seder Tannaim V'Ammoraim, Iggeret Rav Shrira Gaon, Sefer Hakabalah (ibn Daud), Rambam's intro to MT, Meiri's intro to Avot, Shalshelet Hakabalah (ibn Yahya), Seder HaDorot, and Shem Hag'dolim.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- For Tannaim and Ammoraim, see Erkhei Tannaim V'Amoraim by [R. Yehuda ben Kloinmus of Speyers](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1_%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%90) ([Vol. I](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/16271)), ([Vol. II](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/16272)). It includes an alphabetical list of all the Tannaim and Amoraim, and an examination of each one's teachings.
- Tol'dot Tannaim V'amoraim by [R. Aharon Heiman](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9F). Another alphabetical listing. ([Vol. I](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/43956)), ([Vol. II](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/43957)), ([Vol. III](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/43958)).

For more general listings, see:

- [Sefer Yuhasin](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/5900) by [R. Avraham Zacutto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Zacuto). It covers (at least) the period of the Amoraim until the authors time (circa 1500) The listing of Ammoraim begins [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=5900#p=160&fitMode=fitheight&hlts=&ocr=). Of Savoraim and Geonim [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=5900#p=267&fitMode=fitheight&hlts=&ocr=), and of Rishonim (which he calls Rabbanim) [here](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=5900#p=272&fitMode=fitheight&hlts=&ocr=).
- [Seder HaDorot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seder_HaDoroth) by [R. Yehiel Heilpirn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jehiel_ben_Solomon_Heilprin) ([Vol. I](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/46817)), ([Vol. II](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/46819)), ([Vol. III](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/46818)). It covers the entire span of history from the Bible to his own day (18th century).
- [Sefer Shem HaG'dolim](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D) by [Hida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Yosef_David_Azulai), [here](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D). This work covers the period of the Geonim until his own time (18th century).
- [Sefer Shem HaG'dolim HaHadash](https://books.google.com/books?id=HENJAQAAMAAJ&pg=PT9&lpg=PT9&dq=%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%20%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D&source=bl&ots=xOFRR8uPdi&sig=TSKzficHofUHjEl1T1pObL5j41g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiku-HH_4XXAhUBTSYKHfi_D2cQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%20%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%92%D7%93%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D&f=false) from 1864.
- The [Jewish Encyclopedia](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/) (pub. 1901-1906).
- Encyclopeida L'Tol'dot G'dolei Yisrael by [Prof. Mordekhai Margulies](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9B%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA#.D7.A1.D7.A4.D7.A8.D7.99.D7.95) ([Vol. I](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/36619)), ([Vol. II](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/36622)), ([Vol. III](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/36621)), ([Vol. IV](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/36620)).
- In many cases [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page), [Hebrew](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99) or [Yiddish](https://yi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%98_%D7%96%D7%99%D7%99%D7%98) Wikipedia will have a page.

Answer (score 2):

You may also find some useful information with these ones (not online):

- [Encyclopedia LeChachmei HaTalmud VehaGeonim](https://simania.co.il/bookdetails.php?item_id=692582) ed. by Margaliot (2
  vols). It cover sages from the Talmud to the 9th Century.
- [Encyclopedia leToldos Gdolei Ysroel](https://simania.co.il/bookdetails.php?item_id=77045) ed. by Margaliot (4
  vols). List the sages from the Geonic Period to the 19th Century.

Online:

- [Kore HaDoros](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=530), by David Conforte (17th century), which contains the names of all the sages  from the close of the Talmud up to his own day.

For an English source (partial online) check [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/77054/4648).