# Can anyone suggest books detailing the lives and philosophies of various sages?

Tags: history, jewish-books, rabbis

I'm seeking out books which go into details about the lives and ideas of the various Jewish sages. Obviously, a single book for all is unlikely but any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I asked a similar question not too long ago: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86430/encyclopedia-of-tzaddikim Perhaps the answer there may help you a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question, and it would help if you specified which time period or Sages you are interested in.

Two sets of books covering broad reviews which I really liked are

- [R Binyamin Lau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binyamin_Lau) set of books on Jewish sages (from [Koren](https://www.korenpub.com/maggid_en_usd/the-sages.html)), [vol 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592642454) on Second Temple period, [vol 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592642462) on Yavne to Bar Kochba, [vol 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592642470) on the Galilean period, [vol 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592643744) on the period from the Mishna to the Talmud
- R Berel Wein impressive books of Jewish history - they cover more than the sages but bring them in context of the history of their times, [vol 1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1422615081), [vol 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0899062377), [vol 3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0899064981), see also [his site](https://www.rabbiwein.com/) with more material to download

An interesting alternative focused on the ideas of great sages is [Books of the People: Revisiting Classic Works of Jewish Thought](https://www.korenpub.com/koren_en_usd/maggid/book-categories/philosophy/books-of-the-people.html) which summarizes the ideas and contributions of great Sages such as Rav Saadia Gaon, R Judah Halevi, the Rambam, the Maharal, R Shneur Zalman of Liadi, R Samson Raphael Hirsch, R Abraham Isaac Kook, R Joseph B. Soloveitchik and many others.

Finally artscroll has a [set of biographies](http://www.artscroll.com/Categories/BGR.html) focused on individual Sages.