# Any suggestions for documentaries/videos related to the stories of the sages?

Tags: history, product-recommendation, torah-study, rabbis, technology

I was curious if anyone would know of some good video resources related to learning about the various Jewish sages of our history. They can be biographical or they can be related to the philosophies of each sage and their Talmudic styles.

I'm open to all categories.

Comment: Not a video so not posting as answers - but for a similar answer on books see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/86683/11501

Comment: "Sages of our history" - any particular era?

Comment: Check out [Rabbi Berel Wein](https://www.rabbiwein.com/). He has  videos on Rashi and Rambam and CD's on history.

Comment: isreali nesher hagadol on ramabam avilable on youtube

Answer (score 2):

There are two animation videos on youtube, one about Rashi and one about Rambam.

The one on Rashi's story is called "[Rashi A Light After The Dark Ages](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSLKfzrIXM8)" (English) and the one on Rambam's story is called "[Rambam The Story Of Maimonides](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaGz2CkJELA&t=61s)" (Hebrew).