# Movie on the history of the sages

Tags: avodah-zarah, art

I've always loved studying about our history and sages. In particular, I am quite a fan of Rabbi Akiva's life and adventures. With the quarantine, I have found myself with some extra time and was thinking on making some 3d animation on some of his episodes (such his dialogues with Kalba Savua, Rachel and Nahum) with recorded audio.

My central question is on idolatry and respect. I would try to be as faithful as possible to the history and the characters while making it pleasant to watch (writing the lines of the dialogues), but I would also be making the character's models (which is a point of concern) and scenery.

I don't know neither the law on art or the opinions of other communities besides mine.

I would like to make it possible for the children of orthodox to be able to watch without concerning their parents.

If I introduced biblical figures such as Moshe Rabeinu, Eliahu Hanavi or David Hamelech, would the situation change?

Comment: Welcome to mi yodeya. I am also interested in writing a story about Rabbi Akiva! For animation, you might want to check out the animated film The Rambam and Prince of Egypt and The Ten Commandments (regarding Moses) if you haven't seen any of them already. Good luck with your film and this question!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any suggestions for documentaries/videos related to the stories of the sages?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87833/any-suggestions-for-documentaries-videos-related-to-the-stories-of-the-sages)

Comment: Many people would have a problem with depictions of Biblical characters, since the depiction takes away from our ability to internalize the story from the source, and adds external elements to the story.

Comment: For comparison, I am under the impression that the animated film *Rashi: A Light After the Dark Ages* (1999) is respected and considered respectful among Orthodox people. It is produced by [The Destiny Foundation](https://www.jewishdestiny.com/) and overseen by [Rabbi Berel Wein](https://www.rabbiwein.com/), former Rosh Yeshiva at Yeshiva Shaarei Torah of Rockland.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This asks about how to make such a video. That one asks about what has been made.

Comment: https://www.bookdepository.com/Akiva-Marcus-Lehmann/9781583306024

Comment: Many commentaries say that you should just not show their face. meaning you have  a face with no mouth eyes or nose. Nevertheless ask a local orthodox rabbi. If you can't you can go on ask the rabbi at chabbad.org or get the instarabbi app on the app-store and ask your question. Do not use the ste for psak halacha generally.